# call multiple method using call_user_func_array

Tags: php, laravel-5

i use below code for fetch all relevant model data

```
protected $model = '';

public function getAll()
{
    return call_user_func_array([$this->model, "get"], []);
}
```

its work for now, but how can i handle chain method by call_user_func_array ? for example:

i need fetch like:

```
 Model::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

one solution is (new $this->model)->where(); that i think its a bad idea. is there any solution?

Comment: Any reason for using `call_user_func_array([$this->model, "get"], []);` for get method?

Comment: in my BaseRepository i want define getById or getByColumnName mthod, so i need to chain methods like eloquent

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call getById getByColumnName methods you can use PHP's Magic function.

In your base repository:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if(startsWith($method, 'getBy'))
    {
        return $this->model->findBy(snake_case(substr($method, 6)), $parameters[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("$method not found!");
    }
}
```

And in your model:

```
public function getBy($column, $value)
{
    try
    {
        return User::where($column, $value)->first();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Model Not Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: i use baserepository for reduce code in my models, its not my choice! but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:

```
$modelName = $this->model;
$modelName::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

Comment: this is not my solution, i want wrire chain method in base-repo, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

call_user_func_array use for low level call function and reduce some issue that not my concern for now, instead (new $this-model)->blob->blob can use for chain in normal form. and i thinks instantiate object have better performance then call_user_func_array.